# Nginx not serving from port 80 and 443, but works on other ports

Tags: nginx, firewall, port

After rebooting my VPS, I noticed that all nginx hosts that were bound to ports 80 and 443 started returning ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT and no new entries were being outputted to access.log

I simplified my configuration with which the error can still be reproduced:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html;
    access_log /var/www/html/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/html/logs/error.log;
    index index.nginx-debian.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.nginx-debian.html;
    }
}
```

nginx -t returns good results:

```
[username removed]:/var/www/html/logs$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

The site starts working if I change the port from 80 to 20777.
Running lsof while having the site bound to port 80 returns the following result:

```
[username removed]:/var/www/html/logs$ sudo lsof -n -i:80
COMMAND     PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
gmsrv      1145  gabriel   14u  IPv4 133782      0t0  TCP [IP removed]->[IP removed]:http (ESTABLISHED)
nginx     19124     root   13u  IPv4 130469      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     19908 www-data   13u  IPv4 130469      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

I checked my firewall settings using ufw and ensured that ports 80 and 443 were not being blocked:

```
[username removed]:/var/www/html/logs$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
25                         ALLOW       Anywhere
587                        ALLOW       Anywhere
143                        ALLOW       Anywhere
993                        ALLOW       Anywhere
110                        ALLOW       Anywhere
20505                      ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
20777                      ALLOW       Anywhere
```

Running an online port scanning tool, however, tells me that port 80 is not open:
[image]

The firewall provided by my host provider (OVH) is not enabled, so it should not be blocking the ports either.

Running tcpdump on port 80 and then trying to access the site from my browser immediately displays the requests:

```
[username removed]:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ sudo tcpdump -vvXX -n port 80
tcpdump: listening on ens3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
11:29:50.652067 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 110, id 19322, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    [IP removed] > [IP removed].80: Flags [S], cksum 0x2b2b (correct), seq 3761772921, win 65518, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
        0x0000:  fa16 3e71 c70c 3aa2 64bf 3010 0800 4500  ..>q..:.d.0...E.
        0x0010:  0034 4b7a 4000 6e06 90c8 9e81 134a 3625  .4Kz@.n......J6%
        0x0020:  4891 1973 0050 e038 1979 0000 0000 8002  H..s.P.8.y......
        0x0030:  ffee 2b2b 0000 0204 05b4 0103 0308 0101  ..++............
        0x0040:  0402                                     ..
11:29:50.902774 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 110, id 19324, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    [IP removed] > [IP removed].80: Flags [S], cksum 0x1b16 (correct), seq 2786550702, win 65518, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
        0x0000:  fa16 3e71 c70c 3aa2 64bf 3010 0800 4500  ..>q..:.d.0...E.
        0x0010:  0034 4b7c 4000 6e06 90c6 9e81 134a 3625  .4K|@.n......J6%
        0x0020:  4891 1974 0050 a617 63ae 0000 0000 8002  H..t.P..c.......
        0x0030:  ffee 1b16 0000 0204 05b4 0103 0308 0101  ................
        0x0040:  0402                                     ..
11:29:51.652209 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 110, id 19326, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    [IP removed] > [IP removed].80: Flags [S], cksum 0x2b2b (correct), seq 3761772921, win 65518, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
        0x0000:  fa16 3e71 c70c 3aa2 64bf 3010 0800 4500  ..>q..:.d.0...E.
        0x0010:  0034 4b7e 4000 6e06 90c4 9e81 134a 3625  .4K~@.n......J6%
        0x0020:  4891 1973 0050 e038 1979 0000 0000 8002  H..s.P.8.y......
        0x0030:  ffee 2b2b 0000 0204 05b4 0103 0308 0101  ..++............
        0x0040:  0402                                     ..
11:29:51.903621 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 110, id 19328, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    [IP removed] > [IP removed].80: Flags [S], cksum 0x1b16 (correct), seq 2786550702, win 65518, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
        0x0000:  fa16 3e71 c70c 3aa2 64bf 3010 0800 4500  ..>q..:.d.0...E.
        0x0010:  0034 4b80 4000 6e06 90c2 9e81 134a 3625  .4K.@.n......J6%
        0x0020:  4891 1974 0050 a617 63ae 0000 0000 8002  H..t.P..c.......
        0x0030:  ffee 1b16 0000 0204 05b4 0103 0308 0101  ................
        0x0040:  0402    

                             ..
```

It seems that the issue isn't from the host provider's side. When accessing the site, I used the server's IP address, so the issue does not appear to be related to DNS.

I need help figuring out what is blocking nginx from serving the content from ports 80 and 443.

Other things I've tried:

- Restarting nginx service
- Reinstalling nginx

EDIT: Posting results of **iptables-save** as requested:

```
[username removed]:/var/www/html/logs$ sudo iptables-save
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Wed Jul  6 12:35:42 2022
*filter
:INPUT DROP [107173:5607638]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [112:5566]
:ufw-after-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-after-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-allow - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-deny - [0:0]
:ufw-not-local - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-input - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-output - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-input - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-output - [0:0]
:ufw-track-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-track-input - [0:0]
:ufw-track-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit-accept - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-output - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A INPUT -s [IP removed]/32 -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s [IP removed]/32 -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s [IP removed]/32 -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s [IP removed]/32 -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s [IP removed]/32 -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s [IP removed]/32 -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s [IP removed]/32 -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s [IP removed]/32 -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/16 -i eth0 -p tcp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/16 -i eth0 -p udp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s [IP removed]/32 -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s [IP removed]/32 -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s [IP removed]/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s [IP removed]/32 -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s [IP removed]/32 -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s [IP removed]/32 -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s [IP removed]/32 -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-logging-forward -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-after-logging-input -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 4 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -j ufw-user-forward
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 4 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local
-A ufw-before-input -d [IP removed]/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -d [IP removed]/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-user-input
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -j ufw-user-output
-A ufw-logging-allow -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
-A ufw-logging-deny -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN
-A ufw-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-forward -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-input -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 27182 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 27182 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22005 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 22003 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 22126 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20080 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 20080 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20777 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 20777 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Comment: Don't paste text output as images. For instance, when it gets resized, it is harder to read. // In the Nmap output `filtered` means a **firewall is blocking**. Please paste the whole output of `iptables-save` *as text* (the tiny excerpt that you provided as screenshot explains nothing).

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I've changed the images to text and added the result of iptables-save

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by using the solution from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247952/532896

Although I'm still not sure what caused the iptables rules for ports 80 and 443 to disappear when UFW rules are still there.